# How to use ternary operator in return statement that returns an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, return

I use React 16.0.

I want to return an element conditionally as shown below.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class App extends React.PureComponent {
    render () {
        return [
            <div className="a"></div>,
            {condition ? <div className="b"></div> : null},
            {condition ? <div className="c"></div> : null}
        ];
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this without any extra methods or conditional statements outside the return statement?

thank you for reading.

Comment: I made a foolish mistake lol !! Thank you to everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're inside an array, not JSX. There is no need to use the curly braces, just do your ternary operation and then put a comma after it.

```
return [
    <div className="a"></div>,
    condition ? <div className="b"></div> : null,
    condition ? <div className="c"></div> : null
];
```

Keep in mind, this will create indices with null as their value in the array if the conditions are false.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to wrap your condition within `{}` otherwise it makes it an object within array. Also you need to specify unique keys for each item in the array.

```
const condition = true;
export default class App extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return [
      <div key="a" className="a">a</div>,
      condition?<div key="b" className="b">b</div> : null,
      condition?<div key="c" className="c">c</div> : null
    ];
  }
}
render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/r5lyr0844m)**

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir
 I didn't say it will create an object, I said it will be treated as an object, and since the syntax inside the object is invalid it throws an error

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do it as

```
export default class App extends React.PureComponent {
    render () {
        var b = condition ? <div className="b"></div> : null;
        var c = condition ? <div className="c"></div> : null;
        return [<div className="a"></div>,b,c];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you basically have it!

```
import React from 'react';

export default class App extends React.PureComponent {
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
            <div className="a"></div>
            {condition ? <div className="b"></div> : undefined}
            {condition ? <div className="c"></div> : undefined}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This will render the first div no matter what, and then only the second and third based on "condition" being true.

Comment: You can't do this in React. You'd need a single parent or use an array.

Comment: Sorry forgot div wrapper